# Crash when calling push_back on a vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm literally going insane with this problem, I have tried everything, googled my problem everywhere, and I don't want to go bald by pulling my hair out. I have a `.obj` file parser that used to work, but it isn't anymore and I have no clue why. The debugger that comes with `codeblocks` hasn't helped me at all in discovering the source of this problem, and I've tried everything I know to find the answer. The important section is as follows:

```
while (1) {
    if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "f" ) == 0 ) {
        int vertIndex[3];
        int vertUVIndex[3];
        int normalIndex[3];

        int matches = fscanf( file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertIndex[0], &vertUVIndex[0], &normalIndex[0],
                                                                    &vertIndex[1], &vertUVIndex[1], &normalIndex[1],
                                                                    &vertIndex[2], &vertUVIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);


        tris.push_back(new Tri()); // tris is a std::vector<Tri*> this is the problem line

        tris[tris.size()-1]->vertIndex[0]     = vertIndex[0]-1;
        tris[tris.size()-1]->vertIndex[1]     = vertIndex[1]-1;
        tris[tris.size()-1]->vertIndex[2]     = vertIndex[2]-1;
        tris[tris.size()-1]->texCoordIndex[0] = vertUVIndex[0]-1;
        tris[tris.size()-1]->texCoordIndex[1] = vertUVIndex[1]-1;
        tris[tris.size()-1]->texCoordIndex[2] = vertUVIndex[2]-1;

    }
}
```

the tri class is as follows:

```
class Tri {
    public:
    unsigned short dotProd;
    float normal[3];
    unsigned short texCoordIndex[3];
    unsigned short vertIndex[3];
    Tri(){}
};
```

I have searched high and low for an answer, but I have no clue why it would crash.

Edit 1: So I took a look at the call stack since it seemed to be my last place for an answer, and upon looking deeper into it, I noticed this:
`std::vector<Tri*,std::allocator<Tri*>>::push_back(Tri*&&)(this=0x96f8f0,_x=<unknown type in (exefilelocation), CU 0x750a1, DIE 0x86cce>)`

now that unknown type part looks pretty strange, but I don't know if that's bad or not, since it's a class and not a standard data type.

I guess I'm also supposed to include the desired behavior, which would be to store the triangles i'm making inside of the vector without the program crashing. I also got rid of unrelated code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Strengthening Barry's request. This question cannot be solved without a lucky guess without  more or better information. Too many unknowns.

Comment: nothing is particularly suspect about `tris.push_back(new Tri());` aside from the fact you're dynamically allocating pointers. It's not god awful to use them but in this case it seems like dynamically allocating the pointers as well as the objects they point to is just making extra work for yourself.

Comment: You can also avoid the block of this `tris[tris.size()-1]->vertIndex[0]     = vertIndex[0]-1;` stuff by taking advantage of a smarter `Tri` constructor and passing the vertexes, etc... to the smarter constructor.

Comment: I suspect you've got the compiler set to flag an error on all warnings.  The worst problem I could find is about initializing Tri in the constructor.

Comment: I was asked to add more info about this problem, but I have no other knowledge about it. There's nothing else to the function, nothing else to the class. When I use the debugger, there's nothing wrong with the information being stored in the Tri, and as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the Tri class. I will give up on this project as I'm not about to rewrite the single most important part that everything relies on to work. This function used to be fine, then I woke up one day and it didn't, I hadn't edited it since it worked. No clue what's wrong.

Comment: That's classic undefined behaviour. It works fine until... Whatever's wrong is either subtle or isn't in that block of code. Running the program through the debugging software that most likely is included in your development environment may help you narrow the problem down.

Comment: @DavidHartman Seems like a bit of a shame, I don't know anything about code blocks but i'm sure it will have a call stack and maybe some stack frame snapshot functionality. Just throw some breakpoints down, make sure you're correct on where it's crashing and inspect anything that might be related, i.e. totally un related pointers that might getting deref'd when null.